# Вывод 6 элементов с базы данных

Tags: php

я хотел бы узнать, как мне вывести 6 элементов из базы? Вот мой код ниже:

```
<?
  $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `clients` WHERE 
  `blogersName` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
  $data = mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
 ?>

 <?foreach($data as $datas):?>
   <div class="item wow bounceIn" style="visibility: visible; animation- 
    name: bounceIn;">
    <div class="image" style="background: url(/images/clients/13case.png); 
    background-size: cover; background-position: center;"></div>
      <a href="#">
          <div>
           <span><b>13case</b></span>
          </div>
       </a>
      </div>
    <?endforeach;?>
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы было показано 6 элементов.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в sql-запрос `LIMIT 6`.